# using ubuntu as a client to connect to bitvise ssh server on windows

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, windows, sftp

Ok, lets see if i can convey what i am trying to do as best as i can.

1. I have a bitvise server at my parents house 3 hours away. It is running on windows.
2. I have used bitvise key management system to generate a RSA public and private key pair.
3. I have exported the private key, put it on a usb stick, and copied it to 3 windows clients and 1 ubuntu client.
4. On the windows clients, i am using a basic GUI that asks for the username, IP, location of the private key, and the passphrase used for the private key. Once logged in, it opens a file manager type gui (like filezilla) so i can transfer files via sftp.

ok, list item number 5 is where i am having major issues. I have a VM of the latest stable ubuntu. I have internet connectivity.

what i want to do and i can not get it to work is use the "other connections" found on the left hand side of the home folder, put in the sftp://x.x.x.x:xxxx in the connections address bar so that i can browse the files of the server home directory. I attached a photo of what i mean.

the issue is, i have no idea where to put my private key. On the windows machines, i just put it in a users folder and pointed the sftp client to it. In ubuntu, i have no idea where it looks for the private key or username. I see a .ssh folder(hidden) and i pasted it there but still no go. I do have a passphrase on the private key.

so to recap, i use bitvise ssh server to generate a RSA key, 3 windows machines can connect successfully. In ubuntu, i just dont know where to put the key so that the "other locations" work.

thanks

the image below is not of mine but a tutorial and it does not tell me where my key should go.

EDIT: i am able to use filezilla in ubuntu with teh private key and it works just fine, but from the CLI or the filemanager, it does not

[image: other connections]

Comment: How are you connecting to the server by using command line? What commands are you using for that and also what errors you get?

Comment: SORRY!! i forgot to add that into the edit!!

sftp -P port# -i /path/private_key_name name@server_address

Load key error in libcrypto
permission denied
connection closed

but yet its the same key i used for filezilla and it worked just fine.

the key does have a password/passphrase on it

Comment: What is the output of `cat ~/.ssh/config`? And also how is called your private key file? (not the content of this one but the filename, e.g. `id_ed25519`)

Comment: sorry it took so long to back. 
cat: /home/matt/.ssh/config: No such file or directory.


 After using the -vvv in the ssh command, the more verbose output yielded that the key generated by the server itself, had a corruption issue. It wors with file zilla, but the newer openssh software, does not like the key file. So i am testing out the following:

ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521

then ill just upload the key to the server from filezilla and retry

Comment: Are you sure filezilla uses the same key? I'm thinking that's using another key. Try [generating](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/) a new key for ssh and test it via command line. If you have the same problem again then I think filezilla might be using it's own openssh version and your current version have actually a bug.

Comment: yes, i am for sure certain file zilla is using the same key. I even transfered the key to another instance of windows 10 and it worked just fine with 3 different clients. 

what i have done, i generated ECDSA keys from the ubuntu client and then just imported the new public key to the ssh server. It all works fine now. Something was either corrupted or it was a bug.

thanks very much for all the comments:)

Comment: Maybe something misconfigured in the server was causing that. Glad you have solved your problem! :).